# PWA builder: How to update existing app with Android Package Options

Tags: google-play, apk, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

Am using https://www.pwabuilder.com/ to generate .apk file for uploading to Google Play Store.

Was able to successfully Create New and add PWA for first time to the Play Store, however some updates have been made and now need to update the PWA with latest updates.

For updating a existing app through PWAbuilder, need to change Options:
[image: Dialog with the Options button circled]

and for the `Signing key` section, then need to select the `Use mine` option:
[image]

**How to get the `Key file` for the Signing key section?**

**and where to find the `Key alias` + `Key password` + `Key store password`?**

Am having trouble finding answer specifically for this situation so if you can, please also share screenshots to help be more clear & specific.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I misunderstood and thought this key file and info is found through the Google Play Console, however when reading issue on https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder/issues/961 I came across the post by user `xet7` and that contains 6 steps and I realized with their step 5:

> You will get .zip file that has key file like signing.keystore that has random data, and signingKey-readme.txt that has your passwords.

so I went back to my original .zip received from PWAbuilder website during initial uploading to Google Play and found those two files:

[image]

In the `signing-key-info.txt` you will find the info needed for PWAbuilder's Android Package Options to fill in the Signing key section input fields: `Key alias` + `Key password` + `Key store password`

[image]

and the `signing.keystore` is the file we need for the Key file that needs to be included.

Also, make sure to update App version code and update other fields and can hit DONE button!